# Not loading related data

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following structure:

entities:

```
public abstract class Register
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? CreatedById { get; private set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; private set; }
}

public class User : Register
{
    [Required]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company : Register
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class Db : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<test_entity.Db>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(test_entity.Db context)
        {
            context.Company.Add(new Company());

            context.User.Add(new User
            {
                CompanyId = 1
            });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Global.asax:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Db>());
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Db, Configuration>());
```

So, when my application starts I add a company and a user into database and in my controller I try to get the company with users:

[image]

The result is no users to the company..

But when I get the user in other db context, it has a company!!

[image]

So, entity knows the relationship between the two objects..

If I use fluent api to configure the relationship it will work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
   .HasMany(c => c.Users)
   .WithRequired(u => u.Company);
```

If I remove the property 'CreatedBy' it works too.

My question is, why he can't load the users without the fluent api configuration? and why the property 'CreatedBy' is influencing the result?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to enable Lazy Loading by adding virtual keywords to your navigation properties in model.

```
public abstract class Register
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? CreatedById { get; private set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; private set; }
}

public class User : Register
{
    [Required]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company : Register
{
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

It is convention of Entity Framework. More about conventions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/data/jj679962.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using eager load. It should behave like a virtual property.